# How To Pagination Angular2 with Django Rest Framework API

Tags: python, django, angular, pagination

I am trying to create a simple blog application using Angular2 with Django Rest Framework.
I am implementing pagination in Django, but I do not know how to rendering it in Angular.

API has the following structure.
Entries are paginated every 5 entries.

[image]

ng2app/src/app/models/entries.model.ts

```
export interface IEntries {
  count: any,
  next: any,
  previous: any,
  results: IResults[]
}

export interface IResults {
  title: string,
  body: string,
  created_at: any,
  updated_at: any
}
```

ng2app/src/app/services/entries.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Http } from "@angular/http";
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

import { IEntries } from '../models/entries.model';

@Injectable()
export class EntriesService {

  constructor(
    private http: Http
  ){
  }

  getEntries(page: number){
    return this.http
      .get(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/entries/?limit=5&offset=` +((page * 5)-5))
      .toPromise()
      .then(response => response.json())
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  private handleError(error: any) {
    console.error('An error occurred', error);
    return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
  }

}
```

ng2app/src/app/services/entries.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { EntriesService } from '../services/entries.service';
import { IEntries } from '../models/entries.model';


@Component({
  selector: 'my-entries',
  templateUrl: '../templates/entries.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['../static/entries.component.css']
})
export class EntriesComponent implements OnInit{
  title = 'entries';
  entries: IEntries[] = [];
  error: any;

  public constructor(
    private entriesService: EntriesService,
  ){}

  getEntires(page :number) {
    this.entriesService
      .getEntries(page)
      .then(entries => this.entries = entries)
      .catch(error => this.error = error);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getEntires(1);
  }
}
```

ng2app/src/app/templates/entries.component.html

```
<div class="container">
  <h2>{{title}}</h2>
  <div class="panel panel-default" *ngFor="let results of entries.results">
    <div class="panel-heading"><a href="detail/{{ results.id }}">{{ results.title }}</a></div>
    <div class="panel-body pre-wrap" ng-bind="multiLineText">{{ results.body }}</div>
    <div class="panel-footer">{{ results.created_at | date}}</div>
  </div>
  <nav *ngIf="entries.count > 5">
      (I want to display pagination here)
  </nav>
</div>
```

In such a case, please help how to implement Pagination.

Answer (score 1):

After implementing pagination in the Django backend, querying the backend would return results in the following format:

```
"data": {
   "count": ,
   "next": "",
   "previous": "",
   "results": []
}
```

**count**: The total number of items returned.

**next**: The URL to the next items after performing pagination

**previous**: The URL to the previous items after you have navigated to the next. set of items

**results**: The items requested for from the backend, paginated obviously i.e if pagination was set to 10 items and 15 were returned, **results** would return 10 items on the first request, then after navigating to the URL in **next**, **results** would return the remaining 5.

**Service**

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})
export class OurService {  
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  // Here,we make our request to the backend API, this observer takes in the backend
  // api url as a parameter and performs a GET request
  getAllTransactions(APIUrl: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get<>(APIUrl);
  }
}
```

**Component**

```
@Component({
  selector: "app-transactions",
  templateUrl: "./transactions.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./transactions.component.scss"]
})
export class TransactionsComponent implements OnInit {
  transactions: Transacton[];
  transactionsUrl = "http://.../api/v1/transactions/"; //url to query for the transactions
  next: string;
  previous: string;

  constructor(private transactionService: TransactionService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    // On component initialization, load the transactions on the page
    this.getTransactions(this.transactionsUrl);
  }

  getTransactions(url: string) {
    this.transactionService.getAllTransactions(url).subscribe(res => {
      this.transactions = res.data.results;
      if (res.data.next) {
        // set the components next transactions here from the response
        this.next = res.data.next;
      }

      if (res.data.previous) {
        // set the components previous transactions here from the response
        this.previous = res.data.previous;
      }
    });
  }

  // function fetches the next paginated items by using the url in the next transactions
  fetchNext() {
    this.getTransactions(this.next);
  }

  // function fetches the previous paginated items by using the url in the previous transactions
  fetchPrevious() {
    this.getTransactions(this.previous);
  }
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="page-buttons">
  <button class="btn prev" (click)="fetchPrevious()">
  </button>
  <button class="btn next" (click)="fetchNext()">
  </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try [ngx-pagination](https://github.com/michaelbromley/ngx-pagination) for pagination in Angular 2+.