# How To Paginate Django REST API With Angular11?

Tags: django, angular, api, rest, pagination

I am trying to consume a Django REST pagination object using Angular 11. I not a total coding noob, but I am very new to Angular.

Currently my Django REST api is configured to paginate every 6 items, and the total items in the object is 10. Django then outputs a "next" URL that would work fantastic with Django's string interpolation feature, but is not so easily figured with Angular.

I followed this tutorial closely, not just because it has nearly complete codeblocks, but also because it's legit the only complete code example dealing with Django REST API and Angular pagination that I could find on Google:
[Link to other stackoverflow question dealing with this same issue, but remains unreasolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43424988/how-to-pagination-angular2-with-django-rest-framework-api#)

The Django API outputs this object:
[Django REST API Paginated output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aw4Zf.png)

My Angular model is thus:
[Angular model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fDfWI.png)

My pagination service:
[My pagination service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1821Y.png)

My component:
[Component I'm trying to paginate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EEMNr.jpg)

My rendered result:
[The browser's rendered result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MHCee.png)

And the console error message:
[ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'results' of undefined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OEnrM.png)

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your API response is

```
{
   results: []
}
```

The way you use the response is `response.data.results`. Property `data` doesn't exist in response.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Replaced "res.data.results" with "res.results" and it began working.

Thanks!